# Remove dash from list of dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of dates that are all formatted as such:

```
04-12
05-03
```

I want to remove the dash and put a slash (/).

I tried `.replace("-", "/")`; and `.replace(/-/, \/);`

Any advice?

Comment: Are those dates on their own in different strings, or contained in a larger string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
.replace("-", "/");
```

Hmmm, and there's an annoying min character requirement for answers...

EDIT:

and yes `.replace` does work: http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/yGWgn/1/

Comment: Seriously? You meant replace and wrote `.remove` in your question? I don't know how that would stand up in court. :p

Comment: Is the list an array? Can you show all the code you are trying?

Comment: It is an array, but it's also then outputted to the document into individual divs. I don't care at which end the - are removed.

Comment: @Switz - if you do `myArray.replace(...` that will not work, are you aware of that?

Comment: @karim79: `document.write`? Shame on you. ;o) It actually isn't writing to the document for me unless I change the load to `nowrap(head)` or `nowrap(body)`.

Comment: @karim79: thanks, I got it.  It was my stupidity to begin with. I was doing it correctly, but only changed the ID, not the actual text so I wasn't seeing it on my screen. Gahh, I need some sleep.

Comment: @patrick dw - For the love of God, it was for the example. I thought I was being nice by freeing the user from the usual alert which happens before he even gets to see the page load. <sigh>. Never again.

Comment: @karim79: I don't know. There's nothing like putting an exclamation point on an example with an in-your-face `alert()`. Anyway, I think you took me waaayyyy too seriously in spite of the ;o). Just wanted to make sure OP could see the result. <sigh> Never again. ;o) ;o) ;o)

Comment: @patrick dw - I was not taking you seriously, it was all for entertainment value. Not that I don't normally take you seriously :D

Comment: @karim79: Good to hear. Never ever take someone seriously who has David Lee Roth as his avatar. :o)